# How to redirect text to file or stdout if no filename provided

Tags: bash, stdout

I'm writing a bash script and would like to make one of the input parameters the filename users should write their data to. However, if a filename isn't provided, I would like to instead output the same data to stdout.

Is there a simple way to do this without having a bunch of if statements all over the place to try and check where the data should go?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `exec` is passed only redirections, it changes where file descriptors point to in the current shell instance, instead of replacing that shell with another process.

You can use this to conditionally redirect stdout in-place:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
output_file=$1  # set this however you choose

[[ $output_file ]] && exec >"$output_file"  # make stdout point to output_file

echo "This is written either to stdout, or to the output file"
```

With bash 4.1 or newer, it's also possible to get fancier, allocating a new file descriptor and using a variable to refer to it, if you don't want to override stdout for the entire program and its children:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*)|4.0.*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

output_fd=1                                            # default to stdout
[[ $output_file ]] && exec {output_fd}>"$output_file"  # or override w/ named file

echo "This is written to either stdout, or to the output file" >&$output_fd
```

Either approach is considerably more efficient than using `>>"$output_file"` over and over, as `>>"$output_file"` re-opens the output file every time the redirection operator is used; whereas `>&$output_fd` reuses the already-open file descriptor, needing only to run an `fdup()` operation to copy it over to slot 1 for an individual command whose output is redirected there.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit I discovered that if you set the filename you redirect you output to to "/dev/stdout" this will work. So, at the beginning of your script just add:

```
FILENAME=$1
if [ $FILENAME = "" ]; then
  FILENAME="/dev/stdout"
fi

echo "my data" > $FILENAME
```

This should output data to the filename if one is given, or stdout if none is given.

Comment: You can simplify that to something like `filename="${1:-/dev/stdout}"` or even just `echo "my data" > "${1:-/dev/stdout}"`

Comment: Quote your expansions. `[ "$FILENAME" = "" ]`, or else a filename with spaces will have unpredictable results (especially one named `'1 = 1 -o .txt'`, to pick a pathological case). While in modern/unbuggy shell releases it's not generally necessary to quote redirection destinations, `> "$FILENAME"` is similarly a bit safer, just by way of ensuring things work consistently even on buggy shells.

Comment: (...and as an aside: Note that POSIX guidelines specify that lowercase names are reserved for application use. Which is to say, a POSIX-compliant shell is allowed to have `FILENAME` have special meaning, but `filename` _must_ be reserved for application use. Annoyingly, this is one of the many sections of the POSIX spec that zsh chooses to be noncompliant with, but that guideline will save you a fair bit of pain on sh/ksh/bash/dash/etc; I can't count how many people have done something like `for PATH in ...`, and then wondered why their shell could no longer run external commands).

Comment: You might wonder why @CharlesDuffy comments here that you should quote your FILENAME, but fails to do so in his own solution. The difference is the use of the double brackets, that has a special handling of variables (just like `for ((i=0;i<10;i++))` that can be done without `$` characters). Demo: After `f="with space"` The test `[ $f = "with space" ]; echo "Yes"` fails and `[[ $f == "with space" ]]; echo "Yes"` works.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, such scripts use this simple convention (also shared by many *NIX utilities such as `grep`, `cat`, `cut`, `paste`, etc):

```
# Write to STDOUT by default:
script_name

# Redirect STDOUT to a file specified by the user:
script_name > out_file
```

This way, there is no need for an extra parameter to specify the output file.